# Understanding function call for tkinter button command

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working through a tutorial on tkinter. I adapted some code, with the idea that every time you clicked on the button we'd create a new text label in the row below. What is confusing me is that when I write `command=click` it works, but when I write `command = click()` the function is executed a single time at the beginning of the script but not when the button is pressed. The first behaves as I'd expect. The second behaviour confuses me, as I would expect it to raise an error not perform the function once without pressing the button.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


position = {"Loc":1}
def click(position=position):
    Label(root, text="ta").grid(row=position["Loc"], column=0)
    position["Loc"] = position["Loc"] + 1
    return

but = Button(root, text="click here to do nothing",command=click())
but.grid(row=0,column=0)



root.mainloop()
```

Note: I found the answer below more helpful than the answer to the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared) , because it made explicit that arguments are evaluated first before being passed into the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the command bound to a Button or event executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared)

Comment: in part - but it doesn't seem to explain why something happens at all rather than an error. I.e., command expects to receive a reference to function, but actually is set equal to the return value of a function.

Comment: @ClownDown question now edited. The explanation that the argument variables are evaluated first (while in hindsight obvious) was not explicit in the other question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a function in Python (like `but = Button(root, text="click here to do nothing",command=click())`), first all of the arguments get evaluated and then passed to the function. So, you are calling `click()` and then assigning its return value to the command. If it returns None or something else that Button can handle you will get no error. When you pass just `click`, you actually tell the function that it is supposed to call that function whenever you click the button.

Some simple code to clarify the issue:

```
def foo(bar):
    print("\tCalling function {} from foo".format(bar))
    if bar:
        bar()

def fun():
    print("\tExecuting fun function")


print("\nPassing function")
foo(fun)

print("\nPassing function return value")
foo(fun())
```

If you check out the outputs you will notice that they get executed in different order - in the second case, fun is executed first, returns None and than that None value is given to foo as a bar argument.

```
Passing function
    Calling function <function fun at 0x000001A79F8863A0> from foo
    Executing fun function

Passing function return value
    Executing fun function
    Calling function None from foo
```

As to why there is no error - why would there be?
Both are valid statements. You could have a function that returns other function and pass it to the button that way.