# How do I make this Tkinter Radiobutton in Python only add the letter that's been selected once, instead of adding the first letter two times?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, radio-button

I am trying to make a Python app with GUI using Tkinter that would allow user to select a letter from a choice of two letters, then the letter that's selected right before the user closes the tab to be added to the array `selectedletter` and printed.

```
from tkinter import *

def addletter():
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    if(x.get()==0):
        selectedletter.append(a)
    if(x.get()==1):
        selectedletter.append(b)


window = Tk()

letters = ["a", "b"]
selectedletter = []

x= IntVar()
for index in range(len(letters)):
        radiobutton = Radiobutton(window,
                                  text=letters[index],
                                  value=index,
                                  variable=x,
                                  command=addletter()
                                  )
        radiobutton.pack()

window.mainloop()

print(selectedletter)
```

However for some reason, instead of only adding the letter that's selected to the array, it only adds the first letter (in this case `a`) two times. For example when the letter that's selected before the closing the program is **b**, I would want the output to be `['b']`, but instead what I get is `['a', 'a']`. How do I get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take off the brackets from the `command=addletter` after that it should work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68588165/understanding-function-call-for-tkinter-button-command) is an explanation.

```
from tkinter import *

def addletter():
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    if(x.get()==0):
        selectedletter.append(a)
    if(x.get()==1):
        selectedletter.append(b)
    print(selectedletter)


window = Tk()

letters = ["a", "b"]
selectedletter = []

x= IntVar()
for index in range(len(letters)):
        radiobutton = Radiobutton(window,
                                  text=letters[index],
                                  value=index,
                                  variable=x,
                                  command=addletter
                                  )
        radiobutton.pack()

window.mainloop()

print(selectedletter)
```